# Powershell ISE console window command line word wrap

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am bothered by the Powershell ISE console window. There is no word wrap feature in the command line. When I am using it, if my command line is very long, I will go too far away from the command. Is there any method to fix the width of command line?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't be, as it's based on a CMD window which only has width, and no word wrap. Edit window might have word wrap, but, as with VB, wrapping one command line requires escaping a CR character, so this is unfeasible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly no, through development yes. Easiest method is to use ISESteriods, that alters the ISE to enable the features you are looking for.

As mentioned about in this [link](https://cantoriscomputing.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/ise-steroids-2/)

Comment: wow, this stuff turns ISE into a full-fledged IDE, from the looks of it.

Comment: Word Wrap is working with Steroids - there lis a line comment button/short cut (`ctrl+shift+b`) but it only Highlights a block/part of the line. It says `hold ctrl` for line commenting. Is this a bug?